# How to make of elements inside multiple <mat-option> of a <mat-select> even in width? (Angular)

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I´m trying to create a filter component that we can use through all our app. We are doing that using the material-angular library.

It works fine, it shows the list of products to select, but, as you can see, every iteration of mat-option returns two values, a short description and a long description.

[image]

As you can see, the width of the different options varies, adjusting to the width of the short description (the one in bold).

What I´m trying to achieve is to have the width of the options adjust to the width of the longest text, as seen below.

I cant use a fixed size, because this is just one of the MANY filters that I´m going to use, and I need a global solution that allows me to reutilize the filter component.

[image]

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [ngSwitch]="filter.className" (focus)="getValuesActiveFilter(filter)" (selectionChange)="checkFilters()"
        [formControl]="filter.control" placeholder="{{filter.placeholder|i18n}}" [multiple]="filter.multiple">
        <span *ngSwitchDefault class='filter-default'>

            <mat-option class='mat-flex' *ngFor="let valor of filter.filteredValues | async" [value]="valor">
                <span class='short-desc'>
                    <filters-render [renderTagYesNo]="false" [valor]="valor" [filter]="filter"></filters-render>
                </span>
                <span class='long-desc'>
                    &nbsp;{{valor.desc}}
                </span>
            </mat-option>

        </span>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

```
.mat-option-text{
        display: flex!important;

        .short-desc{ flex: 0 0 auto;}
        .long-desc{ flex: 1 0 auto;}
    }
```

Comment: This is a classic layout issue - the same as trying to stack two <table> elements and have their columns line up perfectly while at the same time having their widths automatically adjust to content. You might want to look for a more general solution to that kind of problem since it isn't specific to either mat-select or angular material.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought but I wanted to see if there was a solution that didn't occurred to me, thank you!

Comment: There are probably things you can do in Angular that might make it easier but I expect the general approach would be the same. Sorry I can't be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

This was something that I was looking to do today and after much digging around I couldn't find anyone else that had done it (almost 5 years after this was asked), so I set about finding a solution myself.

I don't want this to happen for all of my select lists so I used `panelClass` to add a class to the dropdown panel (from
https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#adding-custom-styles-to-the-dropdown-panel ) I called mine `options-as-table` but you can call it whatever you want.

Next up was to look at the markup created for `mat-option` and map out all the levels to table elements (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#internal helped with this). I use multiple `span` elements in my `mat-option` to represent the table cells. Setting the css `display` properties on the elements sort of worked, but there were lots of existing styles that no longer worked (like the height of the options) so I had to get creative and move some styles to other elements to get things to look similar enough.

After an hour or so I ended up with this for the styles:

```scss
.mat-mdc-select-panel.options-as-table {
  display: table; // <table>

  mat-option.mat-mdc-option {
    display: table-row-group; // <tbody>
    height: 48px;

    .mdc-list-item__primary-text {
      display: table-row; // <tr>

      > span {
        display: table-cell; // <td>
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 0 16px;
      }
    }

    mat-pseudo-checkbox.mat-pseudo-checkbox {
      // because this gets added as a sibling to .mdc-list-item__primary-text which we are using as the row equivalent we need to position it absolutely so it doesnt break the display on the selected option
      position: absolute;
      right: 15px;
      top: 15px;
    }
  }
}

.cdk-overlay-pane:has(.options-as-table) {
  max-height: 275px;
  overflow-y: auto;

  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0px 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

You can see it in action here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/uwotzx?file=src%2Fstyles.scss